# Adding and Subtracting Total Based on Quantity?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has several options. A person can pick several products by hitting a `+` and `-` button which changes the quantity of an item. What I want to happen is at the same time the total is also changed.

I know how to change the quantity but what I am unsure of how to do is add the price together correctly.

In other words if a person selectsone product at $32.00 two times and another at $62.00 the total should be $126.00

How do I do this?

Here is sample of the HTML code being used:

```
<ul class="large-block-grid-3">
 <li>
  <label for="CAT_Custom_410672">Veloce - $32.00</label>
   <input type="text" class="cat_textbox quantity" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
   <input type="hidden" class="ik-price" value="32.00">
     <ul class="button-group radius button-click">
       <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label for="CAT_Custom_410680">Spin Pen - $62.00</b></label>
   <input type="text" class="cat_textbox quantity" id="CAT_Custom_410680" name="CAT_Custom_410680" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
   <input type="hidden" class="ik-price" value="62.00">
    <ul class="button-group radius button-click">
     <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
   <label for="CAT_Custom_410681">Waxcalibur - $160.00</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="cat_textbox quantity" id="CAT_Custom_410681" name="CAT_Custom_410681" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" class="ik-price" value="160.00">
      <ul class="button-group radius button-click">
        <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In looking around Google and SO I came across several examples that show adding one field together or adding the fields in a diferent manner than what I am doing. I do not know how to adapt those scripts to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated, javascript isn't my strongest suit.

Here is the script I am using to quantity tick up or down:

```
$(function() {
 $(".button-click a").on("click", function() {

  var $button = $(this);
  var oldValue = $button.closest("ul").prev().val();

  if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseInt(oldValue) +1;

    } else {
    if (oldValue > 0) {
      var newVal = parseInt(oldValue - 1);
    } else {
      newVal = 0;
    }
  }
  $button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);

 })
});
```

If this script can be modified to not only change the quantity but add the totals that would be great!

Note: The HTML output of the total is an input field:

```
<input type="text" class="cat_textbox amount" id="Amount" name="Amount" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".button-click a").on("click", function () {
    var $button = $(this);
    var txt = $button.closest("ul").prev().parent().find(".quantity"); //find quantity
    var oldValue = $(txt).val(); //find amount

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
        var newVal = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;

    } else {
        if (oldValue > 0) {
            var newVal = parseInt(oldValue - 1);
        } else {
            newVal = 0;
        }
    }
    $(txt).val(newVal); //change value of textbox
    calculate();
});

function calculate() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.button-click').each(function () {
        var amt = parseInt($(this).prev().val()); //find amount
        var qty = parseInt($(this).parent().find(".quantity").val()); //find quantity
        total += (amt * qty); // calculate total
    });
    $('#Amount').val(total.toFixed(2)); //print total
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wrw88/)

Comment: have you entered text?? instead of number?? you can disable input boxes to prevent such errors. [see this.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wrw88/1/) OR use regex so that only numbers can be entered in the textbox.

Comment: I tried `parseFloat` vs `parseInt` to see if that made any difference. It did not. Ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Lynda simply try to put an alert for total in the calculate function and see what comes out....

Comment: @iJay is right. `parseFloat` makes no difference here. it should work

Comment: @iJay - When I tried `alert(total);` I still received `NaN` I also tried adding the radix to the `parseInt` and still no luck.

Comment: @iJay - When I try `amt` and `qty` I receive this error message in Firebug: `qty is not defined` and `amt is not defined`

Comment: @Lynda it shoud be inside the loop. i.e. before `total += (amt * qty);` line

Comment: @iJay - But how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Hiral- I have an exact copy of your code. I don't get why it works in the fiddle but not my page. Hmmm...

Comment: @Lynda ok so now do an alert for $(this).prev().val() inside each loop.See if u get anything

Comment: @Lynda I got the problem you have about 20 `.button-click` classes on that page. Thats why it is not working. Give `ID` to the `.large-block-grid-3` ul which contains 3 textboexes (before next button) and change selectors accordingly. i.e. if id of `ul` is "calculate", then inside calculate(), change from `$('.button-click').each()..` to `$('#calculate .button-click').each()...`. It should work.

Comment: That did fix the problem. I have three groups with one group containing 11 items. How do I add all groups together to maintain the total?

Comment: You `HTML` markup is not uniform. for the rest 11 items, give value of input field `.ik-price` as 1. and rollback the change. i.e. change from `$('#vaproizers .button-click').each()` to `$('.button-click').each()..`.

Comment: I went through and added `<input type="hidden" class="ik-price" value="[price of item]">` in the HTML and rolled back but it still throws the `NaN` error when I do that. I know I have parts of the form for shipping information but I wrapped the areas to calculate together in a div

Comment: @Lynda Because the rest 11 textboxes dont have `quantity` class. Either add `quantity` class to the rest 11 textboxes or change from  `var qty = parseInt($(this).parent().find(".quantity").val());
` to `var qty = parseInt($(this).parent().find(".cat_textbox").val());
`.